# Localization is working fine with Data Annotations and Views but not with Identity Pages ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to implement localization in an application in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1. I am able to localize model validations and Views. However, I am unable to localize the Identity pages of model validation. To implement localization I have made changes in the **startup.cs** file as below:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),                  
                    new CultureInfo("da-DK")
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new LocalizationDemoCultureProvider());
            });
 

            services.AddDbContext<LocalizationDemoDbContext>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(
                      Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalizationDemoDbContextConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LocalizationDemoDbContext>();


            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(); 

            services.AddRazorPages().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }

    }
```

My **LocalizationDemoCultureProvider.cs** class is as below:

```
public class LocalizationDemoCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
    {

        public override async Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            CultureInfo cultureInfoToSet = null;

            cultureInfoToSet = GetRequestCultureById(1); // The Id values come from database in the real application

            if (cultureInfoToSet != null)
            {
                return new ProviderCultureResult(cultureInfoToSet.Name);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private CultureInfo GetRequestCultureById(int Id)
        {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = null;

            if (Id == 1)
            {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
            }
            else if (Id == 2)
            {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            }
            return cultureInfo;
        }
    }
```

After this, I can get resource keys in Views with the help of IViewLocalizer. For instance in one of the views is Create.cshtml as below:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer

@model LocalizationDemo.Models.EmployeeViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>@localizer["EmployeeCreate"]</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Salary" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Salary" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Salary" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DOB" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DOB" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">@localizer["BackToList"]</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

My EmployeeViewModel.cs is as below which add DataAnnotations:

```
 public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="FirstNameErrorMessage")]
        [Display(Name ="FirstName")] 
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastNameErrorMessage")]
        [Display(Name = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "SalaryErrorMessage")]
        [Display(Name = "Salary"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}")]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOBErrorMessage")]
        [Display(Name = "DOB"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }
```

This works fine but when I add resource files for Identity pages according to the folder structure for Login page, the DataAnnotations doesn't work. I need some help because I am stucked here. Please help.

Sample **EmployeeViewModel.resx** file which is working fine.
[image]

Sample **Login.resx** which is not working.
[image]

Below is the folder structure with corresponding Resource files.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the Identity pages workable, there is a different pattern for the inner model.
For example, for the Login.cshtml, LoginModel has an inner model named as InputModel. So the resources file should be LoginModel+InputModel.resx. Resource files structure is now as below:

[image]